# Definition of a pseudo parallelogram

Tags: terminology

Has anyone seen a definition for a pseudo parallelogram ? I have seen that terminology used in an old paper in the Transactions of the AMS, but I am not clear on what the definition is. Some of my current research involves quadrilaterals which are generalizations of parallelograms in a certain sense. I have thought of calling them pseudo parallelograms(or perhaps quasi-parallelograms), but I do not want to use terminology which may have already been established.

Comment: Does that Transactions paper not define the term, or reference some other paper where it is defined?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I assume this is the paper: https://books.google.com/books?id=c37xAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=pseudo+parallelogram&source=bl&ots=AzjvVX0G1Y&sig=AoLLYVLqKir9pQnY8_djCpo3_78&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsqMuqkZDPAhWGSSYKHXp8Bd4Q6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=pseudo%20parallelogram&f=false

Comment: I haven't actually looked at the paper yet except for the part you provided the link to. I was really wondering where else it might have been used and/or defined ?

Comment: Apparently the definition is given in a paper by J. Mercer from 1908, but I haven't been able to locate that paper yet. I will probably just use the terminology since it does not appear much at all in a Google search.